# How to test RDMA performance between two nodes with Intel's IMB benchmark

Tags: rdma

Hello I am new to using RDMA benchmark tools 
and currently trying to use Intel's IMB benchmark 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mpi-benchmarks

and currently, tested all the examples in the document.

However, I have no idea how to use two nodes to test the performances. 
Is it something really obvious?

The only example that mentioned about using the two nodes was

```
mpirun -np <2P> IMB-MPI1 -map <P>x2 -multi 0 PingPong
```

but there is absolutely no description about the node information.

Anyone who is familiar with using these type of benchmark, I really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was to divide the subnet for the ethernet and the Infiniband

In essence the ethernet and the Infiniband should not share the same subnet.

After that the arp table recognized the Infiniband device and everything ran smoothly.

Comment: Are you saying we should separate the subnet to avoid any confusion since the OS cannot tell the request should be sent from either ethernet or IB channel?

Comment: Why not use qperf?

Answer (score 0):

you can using these to specify the nodes infor

mpirun -hosts node1,node2 -ppn 1 -n 2